# How to modify an iterator while iterating over an array

Tags: ruby, loops, iterator

I want to skip a loop x times according to a condition that is determined at runtime. How can I do this?

```
for i in (0..5)
  if i==0
    3.times {next} # i=i+3 also doesnt work
  end
  puts i
end
```

Expect to output

```
3
4
5
```

EDIT:
To clarify, the question is both the `condition` (ie i==0) and skipping `x` times iteration are determined dynamically at runtime, more convoluted example:

```
condition = Array.new(rand(1..100)).map{|el| rand(1..10000)} #edge cases will bug out
condition.uniq!

for i in (0..10000)
  if condition.include? i
    rand(1..10).times {next} # will not work
  end
  puts i
end
```

Comment: Not sure what is the exact input and output of your function. In your example, why not just use `(3..5).each {|i| puts i}`

Comment: @LeiChen, that's clearly how it should be done, so why not post an answer? Maybe `def skip_first(range, nbr_to_skip)`.

Comment: please see my more convoluted example

Comment: For your "convoluted" example, I would prefer to compute an array `keepers` in advance, so you could just write `for i in keepers....`. That might be written `condition = Array.new(rand(1..4)).flat_map do |el| first = rand(1..20); [*first..first+rand(0..4)]; end.uniq # => [7, 8, 9, 18, 6]; keepers = [*1..20]-condition #=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 19, 20]`. I realize there will be other situations where you will need `next if ....` within the block.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

simple method to skip by a defined multiple.

```
array_list = (0..5).to_a
# Use a separate enum object to hold index position
enum = array_list.each 
multiple = 3

array_list.each do |value|
  if value.zero?     
    multiple.times { enum.next }
  end   
  begin puts enum.next rescue StopIteration end
end
```

Comment: You can write that more succinctly: `multiple = 3; enum = (0..5).each; loop do; multiple.times { enum.next } if enum.next.zero?; puts 'hi'; end`. `"hi"` is printed thrice. This works because [Enumerator#next](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Enumerator.html#method-i-next) raises a `StopIteration` exception when an attempt is made to go beyond the end of the enumeration, and [Kernel#loop](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-loop) handles the exception by breaking out of the loop. You could instead write `enum = (0..5).to_enum`, which is arguably more descriptive.